# Layered animations create gaps between items

Tags: qt, qml

I am using a `Row` to layout a modifiable list of items whose size can change.
I want to animate insertions/removals smoothly so I added the `move` transition. 
However, I also want to animate size changes of the items themselves.

This creates two animations: the size change of the resized item and the position change of items to their right.
Together, this results in a gap between the shrinking item and the one to its right.
You can see this effect with the following example code (left click on an item to change its size):

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: row.width
    height: row.height
    Row {
        id: row
        move: Transition {
            NumberAnimation {
                property: "x"
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                duration: 100
            }
        }

        Repeater {
            model: ListModel {
                id: listModel
                ListElement {
                    itemColor: "red"
                }
                ListElement {
                    itemColor: "green"
                }
                ListElement {
                    itemColor: "blue"
                }
                ListElement {
                    itemColor: "yellow"
                }
                ListElement {
                    itemColor: "orange"
                }
            }

            delegate: Rectangle {
                id: rectangle
                width: 100
                height: 100
                color: modelData

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                    onClicked:  rectangle.width = 400 - rectangle.width
                }

                MouseArea {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                    onClicked: listModel.remove(index)
                }

                Behavior on width {
                    PropertyAnimation {
                        easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                        duration: 100
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So the question is how to avoid the gap.
Ideally, I'd like to separate the animation for insertion/removal from the animation for size changes. However, the [documentation for `move`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-row.html#move-prop) says that it is used for

> - Child items that move when they are displaced due to the addition, removal or rearrangement of other items in the positioner
> - Child items that are **repositioned due to the resizing** of other items in the positioner

So how can I avoid that gap while still animating the deletion and size change?

**Please note**
that the example above is only a minimal way to show the problem as I cannot post the real code here where the deletion is triggered by the QAbstractItemModel derivate's row deletion signal.

Answer (score 0):

The gap is created by your `move` property which also interferes with your `PropertyAnimation`. So you should remove that property.

I wrapped a GridView and used in-built properties to handle animation. For example `remove` to define what definition and `displaced` to animate the movement when items get displaced.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 100*listModel.count
    height: 100

    ListModel {
        id: listModel
        ListElement {
            itemColor: "red"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemColor: "green"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemColor: "blue"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemColor: "yellow"
        }
        ListElement {
            itemColor: "orange"
        }
    }

    GridView {
        model: listModel
        anchors.fill: parent

        remove: Transition {
            PropertyAnimation {
                easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                duration: 100
                property: "width"
                to: 0
            }
        }

        displaced: Transition {
                NumberAnimation { 
                    properties: "x,y"
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                    duration: 100 }
        }

        delegate:
            Rectangle {
            id: rectangle
            width: 100
            height: 100
            color: modelData

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.LeftButton
                onClicked: rectangle.width = 400 - rectangle.width
            }

            MouseArea {
                anchors.fill: parent
                acceptedButtons: Qt.RightButton
                onClicked: listModel.remove(index)
            }

            Behavior on width {
                PropertyAnimation {
                    easing.type: Easing.InOutQuad
                    duration: 100
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For example look at the documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-gridview.html#remove-prop

In the documentation of [ViewTransition](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-viewtransition.html#details) you can find more properties in `GridView` and `ListView` like `populate`, `add`.

Comment: Sorry, the example in my question is only a dumbed down version to show the effect. The removal is created by an underlying QAbstractItemModel derivate so I have no control over the deletion.

Comment: Are you saying I should not delete the `move` property ? It should still be possible if you intercept the mouse signals before it gets forwarded to the underlying structure ? Or when does the deletion signal in the row gets triggered ?

Comment: The deletion might not be triggered by user interaction at all. It feels like a hack to divert the flow of control from the usual signals to handwritten code.

Comment: Alternatively you can wrap a `GridView` or a `ListView` around your `Row` and use the in-built properties like `remove` for transitions. I updated my answer in this regard.

Comment: I would have to look into that, but I am afraid that the `ListView` does not fit my usecase. I noticed that the attached ViewTransition properties allow to distinguish between move by adding items and the rest but unfortunately not between move by deletion and move by resize.

Comment: @Nobody It is possible. That is what `GridView` or `ListView` are for. I updated my answer to show you an example. You can remove the items normally and they would animate. At the same time I kinda broke your expanding animation, which would need to be adjusted with a `Transition` for the x-coordinates (since it only works for the right items). Anyway, wanted to show you that you can distinguish between both.